# Prove whether $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt[3]{\frac{k+2}{k^2(k^2+1)}}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Could I get a hint on how to continue with this problem:

"Prove whether

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sqrt[3]{\frac{k+2}{k^2(k^2+1)}}$

converges or diverges."

My first approach was to look at it intuitively:

$\sqrt[3]{\frac{k+2}{k^2(k^2+1)}} \stackrel{\text{for large k}}{\approx} \sqrt[3]{\frac{k+0}{k^2(k^2+1)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2+k)}}$

So I was thinking about doing a comparison test with p-series/$\alpha$-series, but I don't know how to go on from $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{k^2+k)}}$ and maybe it isn't the most efficient way.

Comment: Check the powers on the intuitive calculations again : there is a mistake. But you are getting the right idea : that of comparison to a known simpler series.

Comment: stupidgal123 - Why the user name?  You're still learning. Give yourself a break. You clearly had the right idea on how to attack this problem, as @Teresa Lisbon points out. All of us started out not knowing everything. That's why this community exists: so those of us who don't know can learn from those who do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use that

$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{k+2}{k^2(k^2+1)}} \ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{k+1}{(k^2+2k+1)^2}}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{k+1}{(k+1)^4}}=\frac1{k+1}$$

and then apply direct comparison test or, as an alternative, limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1k$.

Answer (score 1):

For large $k$, using long division
$$\frac{k+2}{k^2 \left(k^2+1\right)}=\frac 1{k^3}+\frac 2{k^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)$$
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{k+2}{k^2 \left(k^2+1\right)}}=\frac{1}{k}+\frac{2}{3 k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)\qquad > \qquad \frac{1}{k}$$ Think about the harmonic series.